# Passing information between projects without referencing one another

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, portable-class-library

I have a solution with three projects, the **BackgroundTasks** which is a *Windows Runtime Project*, **SecondaryProject**, which is a *Class Library*, and the **MainProject**, which is also a *Class Library*. The **BackgroundTasks** is responsible for receiving *PushNotifications*, hence it is registered by the system. I do know that if there is no kind of connection between **BackgroundTasks** and **SecondarPyroject**, when the notification is received the **SecondaryProject** does not exist, since there is nothing that could create an instance of it, as there is no instance of the application.
Now comes the tricky stuff, the idea is that when I receive a *PushNotification* I want to filter it, so what I want to do is to pass it, somehow, to the **SecondaryProject**, so it can validate the notification information and return a value like an `int` or `string`, depending on the result. The problem here is that I cannot add **SecondaryProject** as a reference to my **BackgroundTasks**, because that project is already referenced in **MainProject** and has public methods that I do not want available to the **BackgroundTasks** project.

I've tested with interfaces and abstract classes, but the problem is that my **BackgroundTasks** is a *Windows Runtime Project*, so I'm very limited using interfaces.

In sum, how can I, with three projects (**A**, **B** and **C**), where the **C** references the **B** and the **A** cannot reference the **B** because of the public methods in it that should only be available to **C**, pass something from **A** to **B** and from **B** to **A** again?

Comment: Use interfaces to define the views of your classes, which contain only relevant information. Put the interfaces in a common project which can be referenced by all the other. You can pass the values by interfaces between the projects.

Comment: Have you considered restructuring and using the protected internal access modifier?

Comment: Still, I have methods that need to be public from project B to C. I f I maintained everything in B as internal, I would have to create one protected internal specific to project A and one to project C, correct?